# Select Column is its contain value SQL Server

Tags: sql

I have one Audit Table which have Multiple Column,

Lets Say

```
Create table TestTable ( ID int, Col1 varchar(10), Col2 varchar(10), Col3 varchar(10), Col4 varchar(10), Col5 varchar(10), Col6 varchar(10), Col7 varchar(10));

insert into TestTable values(1,'Ram',null,null,null,null,null,null); 
insert into TestTable values(2,null,1,null,'2',null,null,null); 
insert into TestTable values(3,null,1,null,'2',null,null,null);
```

Now I want IF User run below Query

```
Select *[]* From TestTable where ID=1
```

Then Output should come like this.

```
**ID Col1 
1  Ram**
```

and User run below query

```
Select *[]* From TestTable where ID=2
```

Then Output should come like this.

```
**ID Col2  Col4
1    1      2
```

Column is should not be static, If have value in row that column should come.

Any Idea how to get that results, I need to select the columns dynamically.

Comment: A SQL query returns a well defined set of columns.  You cannot have a query that returns a variable number of columns, unless you use dynamic SQL.

Answer (score 0):

It is not impossible to do, but the query to generate that kind of result would be complex and require dynamic generation of the SQL statement.

Filtering which columns should be displayed should rather be the job of your frontend. It would also be hard for any other system to rely on a result set with a dynamic number of column.